# Android long executing code in onCreateView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, optimization, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment that initializes recycler view with creating its adapter and filling it with data. But that code causes lags when rendering.
Where should I move the adjusting of recycler for it not to block main render?
Fragment takes ~0.8s to render, that looks laggy.

```
// This code causes lags both in onCreateView() and in onViewCreated()
view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.shop_recycler).apply {
    adapter = SourcesShopAdapter().apply {
        dataset = SourcesReference.shopData.toList()
        updateFiltered()
    }
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
        context,
        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
        false
    )
}
```

Comment: There's no way for it to go faster if your datasource is big, you need to implement a loading screen/component. I don't know any beginner-level approach for this but you can try learning some MVVM + coroutines + LiveData/Flow. Then you can manage your loading status that way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be your problem when doing the heavy load on the main UI-Thread, that the loading of the Fragment is not as quick as you liked, because Android stops the UI when loading your data.

You could do the following: Create a Background `Thread` that loads you Data into the List. When doing so the heavy load is not mainly focused on the UI-Thread. When finished you can implement a `Callback` that is executed with `runOnUIhread(new Runnable...)` assigning your Adapter to the List and using `invalidate()` to reload the RecyclerView:

```
 YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(list);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    recyclerView.invalidate();
```

If you like you can even start a `LoadingBar`, then execute the Background Thread and make `LoadingBar.setVisibility(false)` when the RecyclerView is invalidated. Therefor your customer will no have a laggy feeling.